# how can I pass a variable to another method in java

Tags: java, variables, methods

I am trying to pass a variable between methods but I don't know how to do it in this example. 
PS I am new to java

```
public int calcTotalPoints() {
int sumOfDice = val1 + val2 + val3;
int total=0;


      if (threeSame()){
          total= sumOfDice + 10;
      }

      else if (pair()){
          total= sumOfDice + 20;
      }
      else if (allDifferent()){
        total= sumOfDice;
      }
      return total;    
}

 public void printResult() {
          System.out.println("points: " + total);
}
```

**I am trying to print total in a different method**

Comment: Your `printResult` method has an unused variable (`round`). Actually, it won't compile because `total` isn't accessible within that scope.

Comment: `int total = calcTotalPoints();`

Comment: please show how you are calling this code (from main?)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you do the following:

```
int val1 = 10;
int val2 = 5;
int val3= 2;
//you call method as follows
int total = calcTotalPoints( val1, val2,val3 );


//method variables declaration as follows

public int calcTotalPoints(int val1, int val2, int val3) 
{
int sumOfDice = val1 + val2 + val3;
int total=0;


      if (threeSame()){
          total= sumOfDice + 10;
      }

      else if (pair()){
          total= sumOfDice + 20;
      }
      else if (allDifferent()){
        total= sumOfDice;
      }
      return total;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your `calcTotalPoint()` already return the integer so you could do `System.out.println("points: " + calcTotalPoints())`